# Creating query in MongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a collection with documents that have the following fields:

- `description`
- `state`
- `field_num`

I would like to return a cursor to all the documents that meet the following critiria:

- have status "complete"
- and field_num greater than 100
- and that their description does not contain "abc" pattern?

Is this query correct?

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$gte",99)
    .append("status","complete")
    .append("description", new BasicDBObject("$not", ".*abc")))

DBCursor cursor = collection.find("collection name", query, projection)
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: "is that query correct"? -> execute the query, check the results.

Comment: By the way,`$gte` is "greater than or equals 99". That is for sure **not** "greater than 100"

Comment: I tried it, I am getting an error when doing cursor.hasNext(). though I might have a problem in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

> have status "complete"
>
> and field_num greater than 100
>
> and that their description does not contain "abc" pattern?

... can be expressed as follows:

```
Bson query =
        // where field_num > 100
        new BasicDBObject("field_num", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 100))

        // where status is ' complete'
        .append("status", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "complete"))

        // where description does not contain 'abc' 
        // note: this uses inverse matching since the $not operator
        // is not allowed with the $regex operator
        .append("description", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^((?!abc).)*$"));
```

In versions of the Java driver > 3.0 this can also be expressed more simply as:

```
Bson query= Filters.and(
        Filters.gt("field_num", 100),
        Filters.eq("status", "complete"),
        Filters.regex("description", "^((?!abc).)*$")
);
```

The query is executed as follows:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ...;

MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("...")
    .getCollection("...");

collection.find(query)
```